# Tensorflow slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm implementing a regression model in tensorflow DNN framework which takes input of shape (1504924, 127) and predicts the value corresponding (of shape (1504924,1).

Following is my network

```
class q_model:
    def __init__(self, 
                 sess, 
                 quantiles, 
                 in_shape=127, 
                 out_shape=1, 
                 batch_size=32):

        self.sess = sess

        self.quantiles = quantiles
        self.num_quantiles = len(quantiles)

        self.in_shape = in_shape
        self.out_shape = out_shape
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.outputs = []
        self.losses = []
        self.loss_history = []

        self.build_model()
        print("Completed")

    def build_model(self, scope='q_model', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE): 
        with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=reuse) as scope:
            self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, self.in_shape,1))
            self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, self.out_shape))

            self.layer0 = tf.layers.dense(self.x, 
                                    units=32, 
                                    activation=tf.nn.relu)
            self.layer1 = tf.layers.dense(self.layer0, 
                                    units=32, 
                                    activation=tf.nn.relu)

            # Create outputs and losses for all quantiles
            for i in range(self.num_quantiles):
                q = self.quantiles[i]

                # Get output layers 
                output = tf.layers.dense(self.layer1, 1, name="{}_q{}".format(i, int(q*100)))
                self.outputs.append(output)

                # Create losses

                error = tf.subtract(self.y, output)
                loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(q*error, (q-1)*error), axis=-1)

                self.losses.append(loss)

            # Create combined loss
            self.combined_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.add_n(self.losses))
            self.train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(self.combined_loss)
            print("Completed")

    def fit(self, x, y, epochs=100):  
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epoch_losses = []
            for idx in range(0, x.shape[1], self.batch_size):
                batch_x = x[idx : min(idx + self.batch_size, x.shape[1]),:]
                batch_y = y[idx : min(idx + self.batch_size, y.shape[1]),:]

                feed_dict = {self.x: batch_x,
                             self.y: batch_y}

                _, c_loss = self.sess.run([self.train_step, self.combined_loss], feed_dict)
                epoch_losses.append(c_loss)

            epoch_loss =  np.mean(epoch_losses)
            self.loss_history.append(epoch_loss)
            if epoch % 100 == 0:
                print("Epoch {}: {}".format(epoch, epoch_loss))
                print("Completed")

    def predict(self, x):   
        # Run model to get outputs
        feed_dict = {self.x: x}
        predictions = sess.run(self.outputs, feed_dict)

        return predictions
```

The model complies fine but I'm getting the following error when I try to fit the model

```
TypeError: '(slice(0, 32, None), slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key
```

I'm unable to figure out where I'm missing. Appreciate any input.

Comment: where / how are you calling `fit`?  Need an [mcve].

Comment: your `feed_dict` argument in `fit` needs to map tensors `self.x` and `self.y` to numpy arrays.  it looks like you are trying to map these tensors to tensors instead of arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I reshaped the input as follows : # Reshape to input format for network
X_train_rs = np.expand_dims(X_train.values, 1)
y_train_rs = np.expand_dims(y_train.values, 1)
Now I'm getting the error 
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (32, 1, 127) for Tensor 'q_model_23/Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 127, 1)'